# Converting a stored procedure output into Objects through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My stored procedure returns data in following format

`Hierarchy` table:

```
ParentId ChildId  ParentName  ChildName
  1         9     AAA          BBB
  1        10     AAA          CCC
  1        11     AAA          DDD
```

This data can be linked to a main table which holds other properties of parent and child entities such as `Name` etc.

`Person` table:

```
  Id     Name    Age
   1      AAA     40
```

`Id` in `Person` table is linked to `Hierarchy` table.

I need to convert this to following

```
Public Class HierarchyData
{
      public Person Parent {get;set;}
      List<Person> Children {get;set}
}
```

I am calling a stored procedure and storing output in var.

```
this.context.ExecuteQuery<Hierarchy>(MyStoreProc, Paramerters);

Public Class Hierarchy
{
   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   public int ChildId {get;set;}
}
```

Can you please suggest how it can be converted to `List<HierarchyData>`?

Comment: Can you show some more code, especially the one that reads the data from the stored procedure? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So your getting two ids from your database and you want to store them as these Person objects? where's the rest of the data coming from (name and age) or is that still in the database?

Comment: If you are going to read a stored procedure to convert the result sets into a list of IEnumerable objects, why not map this in EF directly? You would have the entities already, and instead of using stored procedures, you would use Linq to SQL directly? You are tyring to achieve the same thing, yet the other way around.

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916873/entity-framework-code-first-self-referencing-parent-child-with-payload. Doing the same thing, however from mapped entities directly.

Comment: My Store Proc does Recursive CTEs (Queries) to do some business logic. I have changed my store proc to return Parent Name and Child Name as Well. All i want now is to somehow convert that to List of HierarchyData class. Some Sort of GroupBy ParentId thing is Required here Perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Say, the list is of type `List<Hierarchy>`. Then you may run the following code:

```
var hierarchyDataList = 
list
 .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)
 .Select(g => new HierarchyData
                  {
                      Parent = new Person
                                   {
                                       Id = g.Key
                                       Name = g.First().ParentName  // NAME FIELD ADDED
                                   },
                      Children = g.Select(x => new Person 
                                                   { 
                                                       Id = x.ChildId, 
                                                       Name = x.ChildName
                                                   }
                                         )
                  }
        );
```

### EDIT

`Name` field has been added in each `Parent` property of `HierarchyData`.

Comment: Can we replace g.Key?

Comment: I have changed this following          Id = g.First().ParentId
                                       Name = g.First().ParentName

Comment: Will this work for All the Parents in the Result Set , confusing as we are using First() ?

Comment: yes, it'll work and you can use in that way avoiding `g.Key`. As we are grouping by the `ParentId` and moreover, the `Hierarchy` table contains both `ParentId` and `ParentName` for each row, so it is clear that each grouping will contain the list of **same** `ParentId` and `ParentName`. For this reason, `First()` should work for all the `Parent`s inside each group. `Last()` will also do the same for the above reason.